# Variáveis do banco de dados não são adicionadas em $_SESSION array

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, query, session

Estou construindo um carrinho para uma aplicação. Quero adicionar o nome, quantidade e preço do produto dentro do carrinho. Para isso, faço:

No header que incluo nas páginas acessadas pelo cliente:

```php
$_SESSION['cart']=isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
```

Na página onde o cliente faz o pedido:

```php
$query_product = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query_product);
$product_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $product_info['name'];
$price = $product_info['price'];
echo $name, $price;
///a variável amount é pega dentro de um input html
```

O output do echo é algo como:

```
Bombom de côco3.00
```

Quando vou adicionar as variáveis que peguei do banco de dados dentro de `$_SESSION['cart']`, elas nunca aparecem. Já tentei atribuir os valores com e sem o `array_push()`, da seguinte maneira:

```php
function addCart(){
    global $amount, $name, $price;
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $name;
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $amount;
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $price;
    // array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $product_info['name']);
    // array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $amount);
    // array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $price);
    print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

O output disso é:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 5 [2] => )
```

Ele pega somente a quantidade informada no input. **Por que não consigo adicionar os valores que peguei do banco de dados?**

Chamada da função:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-register'])){
    addCart();
    Print '<script>window.location="cart.php";</script>';
}
```

EDIT: Tentei repetir a query dentro da função `addCart()` (acabei tirando a função e colocando o conteúdo dela dentro do if), mas descobri que o `$id` estava vazio:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-register'])){
    $id=$_GET[id];
    $db = mysqli_connect(/*parâmetros da conexão*/) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($db, 'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysqli_query($db, 'SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysqli_query($db, 'SET character_set_results=utf8');
    $query_product = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = '$id'";
    echo $query_product;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query_product);
    $product_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = $product_info['name'];
    $price = $product_info['price'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $name;
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $amount;
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $price;
    print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

Dou o get depois de clicar em um botão de um formulário. Isso influencia em algo? O `action` do formulário é a própria página.

EDIT: consegui resolver, só não sei se é a melhor forma: eu tentava pegar o `$id` depois de apertar o `submit` do formulário, então mudei o action do formulário de `action="pagina.php"` para `action="pagina.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"`. Não consegui fazer isso dentro da função `addCart()`, então realmente tive que colocar o conteúdo da função dentro do if onde eu chamava ela.

Comment: Você já deu `echo` dentro da função `addCart()` antes de tentar inserir no `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @Lucas, acabei de tentar, nenhum valor é exibido... Tentei passar os valores por parâmetro, mas também não funcionou

Comment: Então o erro é no momento de chamar essa função, e não dentro da função, você pode postar o código onde você chama essa função?

Comment: @Lucas acabei de postar!

Comment: a variável `$_POST['btn-register']` recebe o `$id` da `$query_product` ?

Comment: @Lucas não, essa variável é o `name` de um input html que funciona como submit do formulário